# How can I get R.java path?

Tags: android

**describe:** I'm intending to get the

> R.java file path

after the  X.apk install in android.

Comment: I'm not an Android programmer, but somehow I doubt that file even exists in an installed application.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: In any of the application you do not need to modify/read the R.java file

Comment: There is no file R.java after it is installed, that is a class that is compiled into the application.

Comment: I doubt it exists, since the R file simply has constants, the compiler probably uses the constants directly instead of the R reference in the final class file.

Answer (score 1):

What you you trying to accomplished though?

When I decompiled an app the R.class files were found in your package path (`apkjar/com/your/package/`):

[image]

These files contains offset addresses as constants that point to the resource location in the apk. If you want to know more details about the apk generation steps etc look [here](http://en.ophonesdn.com/article/show/354).